# Tensorboard logging non-tensor (numpy) information (AUC)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn, tensorflow

I would like to record in tensorboard some per-run information calculated by some python-blackbox function.

Specifically, I'm envisioning using sklearn.metrics.auc after having run sess.run().

If "auc" was actually a tensor node, life would be simple. However, the setup is more like:

```
stuff=sess.run()
auc=auc(stuff)
```

If there is a more tensorflow-onic way of doing this I am interested in that. My current setup involves creating separate train&test graphs.

If there is a way to complete the task as stated above, I am interested in that as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a custom summary with your own data using this code:

`tf.Summary(value=[tf.Summary.Value(tag="auc", simple_value=auc)]))`

Then you can add that summary to the summary writer yourself. (Don't forget to add a `step`).

Comment: @danmane -- thanks for the answer, but what do you mean by, "don't forget to add a step"?

Comment: when you write <your summary writer>.add_summary(tf.Summary(...), step), you need to include that step value, which is equal to your training step, otherwise your value won't update.